How to select 'null' if any null or 'max' if otherwise in a group select?
This is a simplified example of the query I want to do:
select
  t.id,
  case when any(st.end_at is null) then null else max(st.end_at) end as max_end_at
from table as t
join sub_table as st on st.table_id = t.id
group by t.id;

I want to get the max of st.end_at but if any of the ocurrences is null I want null
Obviously the any() is not working :/
What should be the correct approach?

does the solution below works as expected ? if not can you share sample data and results

Hi @trillion, yes, it worked. Answer accepted. Thanks!

glad to hear that. thanks


count(*) counts total number of rows (including null)
count(st.end_at) only counts non-null values

Logic Used:
When the counts are not matching means something is null hence null is returned otherwise max of date is returned.
select
  t.id,
  case when count(s.end_at) = count(*) then max(s.end_at) end as max_end_at
from table as t
join sub_table as st 
  on st.table_id = t.id
group by 
  t.id

you can also use IFF in snowflake:
    iff(count(s.end_at) = count(*), max(s.end_at),null) as max_end_at



works with both options + iff can be used too.
